# search for sub-document value in firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore database that has the following structure:

I have collection named `NBDB`, inside there are documents with the `uid` of each user. For example I have 2 users so I have 2 documents called: `ZxK2BR...`, `xy9BHY...`.

In each user document there is another collection called `MyBooks` and there are documents for all the books the user search.

Here are pictures from my database:
[image]

[image]
I want to make like home page screen that will disaply 20 random images from all of the images that users have in the app database.

From my understanding I need to get inside each user document and search for all the `my books` it has and then to move for the next user.

My finally goal is to read the BookID value of all of the users and to choose 20 random

I used the following to obtain all `BookID` from **specific** user:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference MyDB = db.collection( "NBDB" ).document(auth.getUid()).collection( "MyBooks" );

MyDB.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getString( "BookID" ));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a collection called "mypics" here.  I see you have a top-level collection called "USERS", then each document under that has another subcollection called "users".  "mypics" looks like a field in the documents of the subcollection.  Could you edit the question to state more clearly how you've structured your database, and what the relevant fields of the documents are?  Either that, or correct the code if it's not exactly what you're using.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking for 20 pics from one user or 20 pictures out of all of the pictures for all of the users?

Comment: Im looking for 20 pics from all of the pictures of all of the users as 20 random images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking to do is pull in 20 different images, at random, from any user's sub-collection. That said, if you don't choose to use another structure and wish to have all of the data nested, you can opt for a collectionGroup query.

The bit on "random" is a bit tricky, and you may want to use some hacky ways to make it work. But starting with getting access to the various user's nested sub collections:

All of this data, regardless of user, lives in collections called `MyBooks` so you can run a `collectionGroup` query on `MyBooks`.

The way I would do it, with the random-image hacky bit would be, in partial pseudocode code to give you an idea (I confirmed collectionGroups in the Java SDKs):

```
usedImages = []
for numbers 0 to 19 {
   let num = false
   while (!num) {
     let tempNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     if (!( usedImages.includes(tempNum)){
        num = tempNum
     }
   }

   var allBooks = db.collectionGroup('MyBooks').where('imageKey', '==', num);
     allBooks.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
     });
   });

}
```

The idea with the code is to generate 20 random and unique numbers `num` (probably better ways to do it than what I hacked together above), and then take that number and look for all entries in `MyBooks` where that imageKey exists. This is the hacky way around the random image code, where you would need to add a globally unique ID to each of them.

Collection Group doesn't specify a path of parent collections, so it allows you to look into all collections at once.

In the above pseudocode, you're running 20 collection groups queries.

You can find more on Collection Group queries here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: When I do this collectionGroup query, from my understanding I need to write it as follows: db.collectionGroup("MyBooks").whereEqualTo("XXX", "XXX").get() however inside the MyBooks collection there is again unique id which I dont know to equal to. Also, I wouldnt mind to use another structure if there is some good idea however I saw that documents can not contain much information so If there will be many books it wont work.

Comment: The example I provided uses a single way to retrieve documents "at random." Basically, the idea is to have numbers 1 through N and be able to call on a random number 1-N to use as that XXX you said you don't have. It would need to be created.

Comment: Im still speaking on getting the books from the collection, at the first stage I can deal without the random. the main problem is getting data BookID list

Comment: You can run collectiongroup without a where clause to get the all items.